# Where 0 = 1 in Laravel BelongsTo Relationship Query Log

Tags: sql-server, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm just trying to use `BelongsTo` relationship to retrieve the records,
Here is the scheme:

```
roles:
- id
- title
```

```
users:
- id
- Role_ID
```

I'm using `SQL Server` for Database so the `Role_ID` can pointed as `role_id` I think :D.

and here is the code for the belongs to relationship in `User` Model:

```
public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
```

I also have tried like this:

```
public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'id', 'Role_ID');
    }
```

But whatever the parameters are it doesn't work and when I get the Query log, it looks like as:

```
bindings: []
query: "select * from [roles] where 0 = 1"
time: 1.49
```

Here is how I try to access the relation in the `Controller`:

```
User::with(['role'])->get($someColumns)
```

I'm just fighting with this problem for many times but don't know where the issue is.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: How do you try to get access the relationship?

Comment: let me edit the question @Etin

Comment: I have edited the question please check now @Etin

Comment: Same problem, it should generate wrong query instead of "where 0=1" when you make typo mistake defining your relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the foreign key in get() columns

```
User::with(['role'])->get(Role_ID, OthersColumns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this relationship in your model.

```
public function role()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'Role_ID','id');
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked but for some conditions it look like I have some other problem.

Comment: It helped that's why I voted, but it didn't solved my problem, thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, @Dilip hint helped me to solve the problem.

Please see my updated question this line:

```
User::with(['role'])->get($someColumns)
```

Actually the problem was with $someColumns, because when I was mentioning the name of some columns in get, it was causing the issue but when I replaced it with the following:

```
User::with(['role'])->get()
```

It worked,

So the simple solution is to **not mention the columns name** when getting with relationship `belongsTo`